# Tag "dynamic": Is the description complete nonsense?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just came across the tag [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) whose description reads:

> Dynamic refers to programs which act during run-time rather than at compile time.

which makes me wonder:

1. *Which programs act during compile time?*
2. If the tag is about "dynamic binding", *isn't the description completely wrong?*

I got the impression that the person who created the tag had very little knowledge about how things work.

I think the tag should be declared obsolete, and a new [dynamic-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-binding) tag should be added (with proper description).
Maybe also re-tag where useful.

---

Statistics:

- There are 27,175 questions with the tag [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic).
- There are lots of users with hundreds, even over a thousand, upvotes on anywhere from 1 to over 100 answers.  All the top 20 all-time answerers have more than 100 upvotes.
- Similarly, all the top 20 all-time askers have over 100 upvotes, but each has asked only 1 or 2 questions.
- Consequently, any cleanup operation is going to be a massive undertaking.

Comment: The tag [dynamic-binding] already exists. But questions tagged with [dynamic] are not only about dynamic binding, but also about dynamic allocation, and dynamic whatsoever...

Comment: The description doesn't match at all what it's used for. Even the examples in the wiki don't match that description. And the tag is used for basically everything, from c++ dynamic sized arrays, dynamic linked libraries, dynamic tables, dynamic routing. The tag needs a major cleanup, but 27k questions is a ton of work

Comment: I haven't checked, but if the tag summary (short description) was like it is now all the time, I wonder whether people using the tag ever read the tag summary then.

Comment: @U.Windl I'm pretty confident to say that the majority slice of the pie does not. The tag name needs to be crystal clear. "dynamic" is as ambiguous as you can make it, so where you have issues with the description, I have issues with the existence of the tag itself.

Comment: Looks like [it was created in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92792/2821954), the period when SO was still in its infancy. There's also no major update to the [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5678744/revisions) and [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5678745/revisions) since 2011. Agree that this tag is unclear as it can be.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of users don't even know that tag descriptions exist. If you're reasonably fast at typing, you can type "dynamic " into the tag box without the description ever showing, and the tag will be added. On a mobile phone, the tag description never shows at all, even when the suggestions show up. Putting important usage notes into those descriptions is basically a waste of time.

Comment: C# has a `dynamic` keyword. I guess people having that in their question just use `[tag:dynamic]` without thinking much. (~4000 of ~27000 questions)

Comment: I don't think this tag is salvageable. whatever "burninate" is or isn't, it sounds like the least that should happen to the tag. this tag is useless because it has so many meanings.

Comment: *"Which programs act during compile time?"*: In [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29), it is possible to define functions where part of the code will executed at compile time, not at runtime (it can go in and out of compile and runtime as it pleases). AKA *defining words*. In essence, full control (extension) of the compiler. Executing those functions will modify (typically add to) the current program. [Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fmpbJBjrL0&t=1m2s).

Comment: The tag seems to be used all over the place: 1) the "dynamic" keyword in C#, 2) dynamic libraries and dynamic linking, 3) dynamic memory allocation and non-fixed array sizes 4) dynamic website content (as opposed to static HTML), 5) any sort of "not hardcoding a value". But what's even more baffling to me is what happens when you filter as many technology tags from the search as it will let you: there's still upwards of 7000 questions left, many of them unanswered and with less than 50 views, presumably because they lack any sort of relevant tag. Just washed ashore in this tag.

Comment: I see considerable use in connection with the desire to update somthing in response to a run-time event: list, table, chart…

Comment: mandatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/2318/

Comment: [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30858906) should not have been approved.  The alleged plagiarism is highly suspect: Based the original phrasing being put on Stack Overflow 2012 _by a moderator_ and being an edit based on a previous phrasing, and those error sites being generally sketchy, I'd be quite surprised if the plagiarism did not in fact go the other way.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not so sure about Forth: Is it really a *compiler* in the traditional sense, or is it an *interpreter* that allows to modify the code that is running. I think it's the second (just as PostScript isn't a compiler). I mean: "*A program needing a compiler cannot run before it has been processed by a compiler; otherwise it's an interpreted program*" It's unimportant whether a compiler works on large scale (progressing multiple program sources) or on microscopic scale (processing single statements): First you need to compile a source, then you can execute it.

Comment: What's great is when they use this tag, but then spell it "dinamic" in the question :).

Answer (score 9):

Users use "dynamic" to indicate:

- "something that charges at runtime", for example:

  - UI elements, like "dynamically created buttons", "dynamically added rows"
  - Array sizes
  - Decisions (generally just ifs with variables)

Then there's:

- The C#/.NET type `dynamic` that lets you have late-bound properties, which has in 15 years only proven to be useful for deserializing JSON into an object that then throws an exception of the property you're looking for doesn't actually exist. Or for interacting with COM objects or other systems who only declare (some of) their properties at runtime.
- Dynamic programming, which is defined as oh who cares, it's too broad and has two delete votes ([What is dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065433/what-is-dynamic-programming))
- Dynamic typing, which has to do with ducks (not really though).

I'd say given my first definition and its examples, this tag cannot be saved. Everybody who's beginning to learn programming calls everything dynamic, so it's a "weasel tag". But we're not gonna manually remove it from the 20 or so thousand questions where it doesn't actually apply, so as with so many tags and so few tools, we're in limbo once again.

Comment: just remove it and move on :)

Comment: Do tags ever get removed though?

Answer (score 4):

The description is worded incorrectly.

The term dynamic in computer programming context may refer to various concepts such as:

1. dynamic programming
2. dynamic typing
3. dynamic behavior

The user who provided the description was obviously referring to #3, dynamic behavior such as dynamic memory allocation which occurs at runtime as opposed to static memory allocation which occurs at compile time. Dynamic behavior may also encompass dynamic linking (of libraries).

As the tag "dynamic" is indeed broad, I support its removal and replacing it with narrower tags (i.e. dynamic-behavior, dynamic-typing, etc.)